# Titanium issue with script: Script error: Couldn't find Module: script.js for architecture

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

I am rebuilding an app for a client using Appcelerator Studio and I have come to an impass where 2 of the scripts in the project throw an error when trying to load the app. On Device I have one script fail saying: `Script Error Couldn't find module: script1.js for architecture: arm64` whereas on simulator I have another script throwing the same error but for `x86_64`

I have no experience with this framework and the hours I have spend searching have only showed me resolutions for third party frameworks, which I believe this is not. I am using SDK version 6.0.3GA any help or ideas where to look would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add your script and the code you use to require your script?

Comment: It sounds like you have script.js not properly placed in your code. Where is script.js located, and do you require it without the `.js` in the require?

Comment: @GerbenHofman unfortunately I cannot post the code, it's over a thousand lines long and I have no idea what any of it does, like I said I am simply trying to rebuild the app for someone. Furthermore to answer @RenePot 's answer I have the particular require call almost at the start of `app.js` where I also have another identical calls to different scripts.

Comment: can you post relevant code. Where do you require it, and how do you require it. And where is `script.js` located in your code. That is information missing